# Cardinality of a subgroup after exponentiation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've been studying some abstract algebra, but I don't know how to approach this problem:

> Suppose $q$ is a prime power, and let $l$ be a prime such that $l$ divides $q - 1.$ Show that $[F^\times_q : F^{\times l}_q] = m$ where $m \cdot l = q - 1.$

I have no idea how to approach this question. I tried some examples, namely $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and saw that if we look at the multiplicative subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^\times_7$ under the image of $\phi$

$$\phi(x) = x^3$$

we see that

$$\phi(\mathbb{Z}^\times_7) = \{1,6\}.$$

Leaving the world of concrete examples, we can note that: we have at least two options for our order of the subgroup: $m$ and $l$ which follows by Lagrange's Theorem. Aside from this, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: $F_q^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $q-1$. What happens to a cyclic group of order $q-1$ when you map its generator to $l$ times itself? Say $G=\langle x\rangle$ with $x$ of order $t$. If you map $x\mapsto x^r$, then you have $(x^a)^r = (x^b)^r$ if and only if $x^{ar}=x^{br}$, if and only if $ar\equiv br\pmod{t}$. Or equivalently, which powers of $x$ maps to the identity? That will tell you the size of the kernel and hence the size of the image.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, if we map $x \mapsto x^l$ we have that $x^l$ is a still a generator of our new set and moreover, this element has order $m$ which means that the set itself as order $m$ (since the group is cyclic)? I know I am ignoring your remark about the kernel, but would this still work?

Comment: Not every cyclic group has the same order, so why do you think that just because the image is cyclic, it will have the same order as the group you start with?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I didn't mean to imply that the orders of the groups were the same. I meant in a finite cyclic group, the order of the generator is the same as the order of the group. So, if we look at $x^l$ then this should be a generator of our set so we have $\{1, x^l, x^{2l}, \cdots, x^{l(m - 1)}, x^{lm}\}.$ But this is $m + 1$ elements so I think I have done something incorrectly.

Comment: You forget that the same element may have many different “names”.  $x^a=x^b$ if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$, so your list almost certainly contains repetitions.